# How to convert a math equation string to json structure and parse using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

This is an example of a math equation string `"((VAR1+VAR2)/VAR3)*VAR4)"`

This is my json structure approach, since there are precedences, it would be good (i guess) to pair the results for each row.

```json
{
"variables":[
  {"code":"var1","value":5},
  {"code":"var2","value":10},
  {"code":"var3","value":2},
  {"code":"var4","value":20}
],
'expression':[
  {"fPart":"fp1",  "p1":"var1", "operation": "+", "p2":"var2"},
  {"fPart":"fp2",  "p1":"fp1", "operation": "/", "p2":"var3"},
  {"fPart":"fp3",  "p1":"fp2", "operation": "*", "p2":"var4"}]
}
```

Im struggling to get some efficient code `function parse()` that could read this json and outputs the parsed string `"((VAR1+VAR2)/VAR3)*VAR4)"`, in this case 5+10/2*20

```
  //
  fillExpressionWithValues(variableArray, expressionArray) {
    for (let expression of expressionArray) {
      let f1 = variableArray.find(x => x.code == expression.p1);
      let f2 = variableArray.find(x => x.code == expression.p2);
      if (f1) expression.p1 = JSON.parse(f1.value);
      if (f2) expression.p2 = JSON.parse(f2.value);
    }
  }

  //
  calculateExpression(expressionArray) {
    for (let expression of expressionArray) {
      let fPart = this.parse(expression.p1 + expression.operation + expression.p2);
      let f1 = expressionArray.find(x => x.p1 == expression.fPart);
      let f2 = expressionArray.find(x => x.p2 == expression.fPart);
      if (f1) {
        f1.p1 = JSON.parse(fPart);
      }
      if (f2) {
        f2.p2 = JSON.parse(fPart);
      }
      expression.fPart = JSON.parse(fPart);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update an object that holds the variables each time an expression is parsed, so the string representation of the expression can be used as if it were a variable name when parsing the next expression.

It could look like this:

```js
const
  input = getJSON(),
  parsed = parseMath(input);
console.log("parsed:", parsed);

function parseMath(json){
  // Puts variables into a simple object
  const vars = {};
  for(let variable of json.variables){
    vars[variable.code] = variable.value;
  }
  // Copies "expression" array to avoid mutation
  const exprs = json.expression.slice();
  // Builds string, and adds it to expr object and vars object
  for(let expr of exprs){
    expr.stringRepresention = `(${vars[expr.p1]}${expr.operation}${vars[expr.p2]})`;
    vars[expr.fPart] = expr.stringRepresention;
  }
  // Gets the string representation from the final expr object
  return exprs.reverse()[0]["stringRepresention"];
}

function getJSON(){
  return {
    "variables": [
      { "code": "var1", "value": 5  },
      { "code": "var2", "value": 10 },
      { "code": "var3", "value": 2  },
      { "code": "var4", "value": 20 }
    ],
    'expression': [
      { "fPart": "fp1", "p1": "var1", "operation": "+", "p2": "var2" },
      { "fPart": "fp2", "p1": "fp1",  "operation": "/", "p2": "var3" },
      { "fPart": "fp3", "p1": "fp2",  "operation": "*", "p2": "var4" }
    ]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const config = {
    "variables": [
        { "code": "var1", "value": 5 },
        { "code": "var2", "value": 10 },
        { "code": "var3", "value": 2 },
        { "code": "var4", "value": 20 },
    ],
    "expression": [
        { "fPart": "fp1", "p1": "var1", "operation": "+", "p2": "var2" },
        { "fPart": "fp2", "p1": "fp1", "operation": "/", "p2": "var3" },
        { "fPart": "fp3", "p1": "fp2", "operation": "*", "p2": "var4" },
    ],
};

let result = '';
for (const expressionStep of config.expression) {
    const left = config.variables.find(v => v.code === expressionStep.p1).value;
    const right = config.variables.find(v => v.code === expressionStep.p2).value;
    const newValue = '(' + left + expressionStep.operation + right + ')';
    config.variables.push({ code: expressionStep.fPart, value: newValue });
    result = newValue;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: wow, I wasn't too far away from that! I had that for and that 2 .find() as well. I just thougth that couldnt be the best approach, didnt feel clean eheh. I need to trust more myselft. Thanks @Stratubas

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mathObj = {
"variables":[
  {"code":"var1","value":5},
  {"code":"var2","value":10},
  {"code":"var3","value":2},
  {"code":"var4","value":20}
],
'expression':[
  {"fPart":"fp1",  "p1":"var1", "operation": "+", "p2":"var2"},
  {"fPart":"fp2",  "p1":"fp1", "operation": "/", "p2":"var3"},
  {"fPart":"fp3",  "p1":"fp2", "operation": "*", "p2":"var4"}]
} 
let evals = new Map(mathObj.variables.map(x=>[x.code,x.value]));
mathObj.expression.forEach(x=>{
    if(evals.has(x.p1) && evals.has(x.p2)){
        evals.set(x.fPart, `(${evals.get(x.p1)}${x.operation}${evals.get(x.p2)})`)
    }
});
evals.get(mathObj.expression[mathObj.expression.length-1].fPart);
```